# How to fix: Unicode problem by comparing string with JSON

Tags: python, json, string, unicode

I am working on a weather app. It will provide a list of cities in a json file. The user then can search for a given city and the app will provide weather data.

The search function for the city works "fine". But right know the user searched for a city and I only have the name of it. For parsing the weather data I need the ID of the city. Therefore I created two lists, one for the name and one for the ID of the city. After choosing one city, I want to search again for city again and remember the place of the city in the list. Then I will use the position to get the ID of the city.

```py
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session
import json
import string

app = Flask(__name__)

CITIES = []
ID = []

with open('cities_list/city.list.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for city in data['cities']:
        CITIES.append(city['name'])
        ID.append(city['id'])

@app.route('/city')
def city():
    return render_template('city.html')

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET','POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == "GET":
        # Read cities.list.json file and display cities
        cities = []
        q = request.args.get('q')

        for city in CITIES:
            if q in city:
                cities.append(city)

        return render_template('search.html', cities=cities)

    else:
        inpt = request.form.get("city")
        counter = 0
        for city in CITIES:
            counter = counter + 1
            if input in city:
                id = ID[i]
        return render_template('index.html', id=id)
```

When I run the code I get the error message:

```
if input in city:
```

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, builtin_function_or_method found

I already tried to cast the city variable to an string. But then it says:

```
if input in city:
```

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, builtin_function_or_method found

Happy for any help! 
Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1):

`input` is a `builtin` function.  Your variable is named `inpt`

```
    inpt = request.form.get("city")
    counter = 0
    for city in CITIES:
        counter = counter + 1
        if inpt in city:
            id = ID[i]
    return render_template('index.html', id=id)
```

notice `if inpt in city` vs `if input in city`